# regex.exec() - failing to match string

Tags: javascript, regex

Alright so here's the deal. i'm using [strapdown](http://strapdownjs.com) to render markdown posts. strapdown uses [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) to parse these markdown posts, which in turn uses *regular expression literals*.

I've ***tried*** to extend marked to include the following markdown "extensions" as described [here](http://sam.roon.io/tearing-up-the-carpet) (shoutout to soffes).

## Background Info

literal for underline extension: `/_(.*?)_/`
literal for highlight extension: `/==(.*?)==/`

underline test code (some code omitted, for clarity):

```
var src = "two new features to the marked.js inline lexer. ==highlighted text==, and _underlined text_";
var underline = /_(.*?)_/;
var cap = underline.exec(src);
document.write("<em class='underline'>"+cap[1]+"</em>");
```

which works as expected (outputting `<em class="underline">underlined text</em>`).
here's the highlight test code (again, some stuff omitted):

```
var src = "two new features to the marked.js inline lexer. ==highlighted text==, and _underlined text_";
var highlight = /==(.*?)==/;
var cap = highlight.exec(src);
document.write("<strong class='highlighted'>"+cap[1]+"</strong>");
```

which again, **works as expected** (outputting `<strong class='highlighted'>highlighted text</strong>`).

## The Problem

the inline lexer for marked begins all of it's regex literals with `^`.
ie:

```
tag: /^<!--[\s\S]*?-->|^<\/?\w+(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*?>/,
link: /^!?\[(inside)\]\(href\)/,
reflink: /^!?\[(inside)\]\s*\[([^\]]*)\]/,
nolink: /^!?\[((?:\[[^\]]*\]|[^\[\]])*)\]/,
strong: /^__([\s\S]+?)__(?!_)|^\*\*([\s\S]+?)\*\*(?!\*)/
```

so naturally, i feel as though i should do the same. i modify my literals like this:
literal for underline extension: `/^_(.*?)_/`
literal for highlight extension: `/^==(.*?)==/`

and then, **highlighting stops matching**. interestingly, **underline continues to match**.

I realize this might be a question that requires some knowledge of how marked works, but it usually can't hurt to ask...right?

### Update 1

you can see what i've worked up (which requires marked.js) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CebQa/4/). To see how marked is being told to parse markdown with my extensions, you can **check out line 658** [here](https://github.com/b3ngr33ni3r/marked/commit/7cec031b6f5ed2996dbf842b5b3a33f16ebab894)

Comment: `/^\_(.*?)\_/.exec(src)` does not match for me. Or are you using it in the lexer?

Comment: Btw, the underscore `_` does not need to be backslash-escaped

Comment: @Bergi i've updated the above to not do the unnecessary escaping. it is matching for me using exactly that test code. [heres a slightly tweaked jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CebQa/) (it doesn't use document.write)

Comment: Nope, once you [add the `^`](http://jsfiddle.net/CebQa/1/) it stops matching as expected.

Comment: @Bergi ah yeah. that [requires marked](http://jsfiddle.net/CebQa/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the `underline` and `stronghighlight` regexes a bit, and added `|==` to the `text` regex to make it work:

```
text: /^[\s\S]+?(?=[\\<!\[_*`]|==| {2,}\n|$)/,
stronghighlight: /^==([^=]+)==/,
underline: /^_([^_]+)_/
```

My jsfiddle test page is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CebQa/5/). For the sake of simplicity, I copied marked.js at the beginning and edited it in place.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are mixing `=` and `-` again: you have `stronghighlight: /^--(.*?)--/`, but in the text you have `==text==`.

Next, have a look at this line:

```
text: /^[\s\S]+?(?=[\\<!\[_*`]| {2,}\n|$)/
```

This defines a normal block of text. It defines "text" as anything that is before `\`, `<`, `!`, `[`, `_`, or `*`.
Your `-` or `=` isn't there, so your formatting is consumed by text blocks.

Comment: I'm not sure where I've seen this line, I can't find it again.